# .Net Core 3.1, WCF connected services doesn't bind the name property in console app

Tags: wcf, .net-core

I added a wcf service in console application and I executed it. Everything is looking good without just one property.

The ***name*** property value always is null. When I execute with SoapUI, that has a value.

[image]

I was tried with the same parameter values but I didn't receive the ***name*** value. The others haven't any problem. Just the name property doesn't bind. Why?

[image]

Could you help me, pls?
Thanks.

Comment: Of course. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, if the **name** received in SoapUI is not null, but the **name** received by the client is null, there should be some problems with your client.After my test, I found that this error will occur if the property in the client class does not add DataMember.You need to make sure that DataMember exists on your **name** property.

[image]

If you are a proxy class generated by a service reference, you need to find the class that contains the **name** property and check whether the **name** property has **[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]**.

[image]

If you are calling the service through the channel factory, make sure that the **name** property exists **[DataMember]**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's generated from a service reference. I tried your suggestion but doesn't work.

Comment: What is the structure of the categoryProduct on your server? Check the name property of the server-side for [DataMember].

Comment: I checked and added with manual but does not work. I created net framework application and I added Web Service References, finally, it's worked

Comment: That should be caused by the server updating the categoryProduct and the client not updating the service reference in time.

Comment: The categoryProduct of the server-side and the categoryProduct of the client-side must be consistent.

Comment: After the server-side is modified, ensure that the client-side must update the service reference.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post but I had the same problem today

I have resolved removing **Order** argument from **System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute** of all property in class model generated by "add service reference" function.

```
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=10)]
    public string Territory_Code
    {
        get
        {
            return this.territory_CodeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.territory_CodeField = value;
        }
    }
```